# prove that $g$ is symmetric bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $J: V\to V$ be a linear opertor where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R $. Assume that $J^2 = -Id$. Let $f:V\times V \to \mathbb R$ be a skew-symmetric non degenerate bilinear form. Define bilinear form $g:V\times V \to \mathbb R$ by:
$$ g(a,b)=f(a,J(b)) $$
Prove that $g$ is a symmetric positive definite. Any suggestion? thanks for helpers!

Comment: You need additional hypotheses as this is false as stated. For example, $f$ could be identically zero. You want $J$ to be compatible with $f$ (i.e. $f(J(a), J(b)) = f(a, b)$), and for $J$ to tame $f$ (i.e. $f(a, J(a)) > 0$ for all $a \neq 0$). Under these conditions, $g$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese You are right. I forgot to say that $f$ is non degenerate. I have edited the question. I have no additional info.

Comment: It's false. Let's look at the $2$-by-$2$ matrix version of the statement. Let $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0& 1\\-1& 0\end{bmatrix}$. Note: $J^2=-I$. Let $f$ be given by $f(x,y)=x^TSy$, where $S=J$, and so $f$ represents a nondegenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form. Then you are asking if $g(x,y)=x^TSJy$ represents a positive definite symmetric bilinear form. But $SJ=J^2=-I$ has only negative eigenvalues! It's symmetric though.

Comment: Note that $f$ and $-f$ are skew symmetric at the same time, but you cannot expect $g$ and $-g$ to be positive at the same time.